# Prevent Decompilation of jar containing Java 8 code

Tags: jar, decompiling, java-8

I am developing my app using **Java 8** and I need to prevent my App from Decompilation. As I've done research in **Progaurd** too , as **progaurd** is **supported until java 7** but am using **java8** so anybody suggest any solution to prevent my App from decompiling.

Comment: Support for JDK 8 seems to be on the way: http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/138/

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. is there anyother way to prevent this code in java 8

Comment: I guess, at the moment decompilers will have trouble with Java 8 code too.

Comment: @Holger Procyon and CFR have handled the new Java 8 constructs for some time now.

Answer (score -1):

write a custom class loader that will decrypt your class files. that way the file on disk is actually undecompileable (and if you encrypt the whole file, not eve a valid jar). its not fool proof, but a good start.

Comment: Just a start... Your method can be easily be bypassed by changing 27 lines of OpenJDK. Take a look on this page : 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/gun-great-equalizer-openjdk

Comment: agreed, obfuscation and encryption can only go so far in an IL.